# Display all the records when due date is less than current date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am having a Quote model which consists of due_date and other fields.

I need to write a condition where we have to display all the records where due_date (which is date data type and stored in database as yyyy-mm-dd format) is less than current date.
For example, current_date is today's date, so I need to display all the records till yesterday.

I wrote a condition but didn't work, can you tell me where I went wrong?

```
  def past_quotes
      @items = []
      current_date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
      daily_items = Quote.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company).where('due_date' < current_date)
      @items << Item.new(items: daily_items) unless daily_items.empty?
  end
```

But still displaying all the records, I think condition is wrong.

Comment: What's the `@account` variable? Where is it initialised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a string when comparing the dates. `ActiveRecord` should be able to handle dates directly

```
      daily_items = Quote.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company).where('due_date < ?', Date.today)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try following query:

```
def past_quotes
      @items = []
      daily_items = Quote.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company).where('due_date < DATE(?)', Time.now)
      @items << Item.new(items: daily_items) unless daily_items.empty?
  end
```